# MS Access SQL Query criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

Using ms access SQL Queries
I need to find the criteria 20140704 out of the 6592 records available.

The SQL Statement:

```
SELECT nbcn_trade_transactions.Tran_Trading_Process_Date
FROM nbcn_trade_transactions
WHERE (((Tran_Trading_Process_Date)=20140704));
```

Query Design

```
Field: Tran_Trading_Process_Date
Table: nbcn_trade_transactions
Criteria: 20140704
```

and when I click run.
The records is down to 229 out of 6592
BUT, the problem is I get mixed dates with it

```
20140703
20140624
20140704
20140704
20140613
20140630
```

and etc...

But I only need it to show **20140704**

What is the problem???

Side Note;
**Datatype is Integer**

It works perfectly When I use HeidiSQL.
It only Shows 20140704, but not the same case with MS Access.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column `Tran_Trading_Process_Date`?

Comment: You should not treat dates this way.  I'm not sure what the precision on a number type is, but it is likely your problem. As Relevant tersely suggests, you could try wrapping your number in quotes.  But the best solution is to treat a date as a date.

Comment: But, What I don't understand is it works fine using HeidiSQL.
I don't think there is a problem with MS access.

Comment: It shouldn't make a big difference, The Datatype is Integer NOT number. My bad!

Comment: Integer type range in Access is only -32768 to 32767.  Far too short for your value.  A long goes from -2 billion to 2 billion which seems a more likely candidate

Comment: Did you try putting `= 20140704` ? Did you try anything else? I'm also curious as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me: `SELECT t.SomeDate FROM SomeTable t WHERE t.SomeDate=20140704` Data type is Long Integer, MS Access 2010

Comment: The problem is likely something to do with the ODBC connectivity!